# Тестирование Exception в JUnit5

Tags: java, массивы, юнит-тесты, junit

Всем привет. У меня возник вопрос по поводу тестирования кастомного `Exception`. У меня есть класс:

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException{
    private final String zhliga;

    public  CustomException(String warningMessage,String zhliga) {
        super(warningMessage);
        this.zhliga = zhliga;
    }

    public String getZhliga() {
        return zhliga;
    }
}
```

`CustomException` я выкидываю в методе, который сохраняет объект в массив, при выходе за пределы массива.

```
public void save(Object obj) {
    int index = getIndex(obj.getZhliga());
    if (index >= 0) {
        throw new ExistStorageException(obj.getZhliga());
    } else if (size >= ARRAY_LIMIT) {
       throw  new CustomException("Array overflow", obj.getZhliga());
    } else {
        addObjectToArray(obj, index);
        size++;
    }
}
```

Так вот вопрос как протестировать в `Junit5` мой `CustomException` отдельным методом? Благодарю, что уделили внимание моему вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю как-то так:

```
@Test
public void customExceptionThrown() {
    CustomException exception =
            assertThrows(CustomException.class, () -> {
                for (int i = 0; i <= ARRAY_LIMIT; i++) {
                    save(new Object());
                }
            });
    assertEquals(
            "Array overflow",
            exception.getMessage());
}
```

Соответственно на последней итерации когда `i` будет равен `ARRAY_LIMIT` мы получим наше кастомное исключение `CustomException` и проверим, что в нем содержатся необходимые данные.

Либо уже нужно из изначального метода вынести процедуру вставки в отдельный метод и тестить отдельно.

Comment: Спасибо, смысл ясен. Но наверное надо ARRAY_LIMIT +1 сделать иначе исключение не выброситься

Comment: @Kekcoe Не нужно, т.к. `<=`. Но может быть и `ARRAY_LIMIT +1`, т.к. Вы не показывали инициализацию массива